# What's wrong with my ruby lazy evaluation

Tags: ruby

Here is my simple program to demonstrate the lazy evaluation concept.

```
class A
  def x
    y += 1
  end

  def y
    @y ||= 0
  end
end

A.new.x
```

But I got this result when running this program

> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Am I doing something wrong?

When `@y` is an array, thing works perfectly.

```
class A
  def x
    y << rand(10)
  end

  def y
    @y ||= [] 
  end
end

a = A.new
a.x
```

**UPDATE**

Finally I understand the problem. Ruby is pass-by-value. When I call method `y` in the first example, Ruby doesn't care about the instance_variable, it copies and returns the value of `@y` only.

In the second example, Ruby still copies and returns the value of `@y` variable. But in this case, `@y` is a pointer of the real array, and the copy of this pointer still points to the same array.

But why the error is `undefined method + for nil`, I expect that the y + 1 which y equal to the value of @y (0). So why it returns `nil` for y in this case?

Comment: _"Ruby is pass-by-value"_ – you don't pass any arguments.

Comment: When you've encountered an error that you report in your question, you should specify the line on which it occurred. More generally, exception message contain valuable information that often pinpoint the error. Pay careful attention to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to understand what `y += 1` really does. `y += 1` is the equivalent to:

```
y = y + 1
```

That means you just told Ruby you want to assign `y + 1` to the local variable `y`. Because Ruby prefers to read from local variables over calling methods, it uses the current value of the local variabel `y` and tries to add `1`. But the local variable `y` is still `nil` at this moment, therefore this operation raises a `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` exception.

I guess you expected `y += 1` to call the method `y`, add `1` and write result back to `@y`. To achieve this you have to change your code a bit to:

```
class A
  attr_writer :y

  def x
    self.y += 1
  end

  def y
    @y ||= 0
  end
end

a = A.new
a.x
#=> 1
a.x
#=> 2
```

`self.y` ensures that you read the method `y` and do not create a local variable. Furthermore you need a setter method `attr_writer` to be able to call `y =`.

Why does your second example work out of the box? Because `<<` isn't a shortcut that creates a local variable, therefore it receives the array from `y`. And `<<` shifts a value into that array in place without the need to call a setter method like `y =`.

Interesting read in this context: [What Ruby’s ||= (Double Pipe / Or Equals) Really Does](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html)